# How do I get my dates to properly align to the start/end of each week?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a simple query to take a date and identify the start and end of the week that the date falls in (i.e. for 3/3/2021 the WEEKSTART value would be 3/1/2021 and the WEEKEND value would be 3/7/2021).

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT
 CAST(DD.Date as Date) AS DATE_
 ,CONVERT(Date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, CAST(DD.Date as Date)), 0)) AS WEEK_START
 ,CONVERT(Date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, CAST(DD.Date as Date)), 0)+6) AS WEEK_END
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE DateSkey BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210301'
```

When I pass a date through the query everything lines up correctly except Sundays. See below for output example:

| Date | WEEK_START | WEEK_END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-23 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-24 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-25 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-26 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2021-02-28 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-07 |

The problem with the above example is that the Sunday value (2021-02-28) needs to have a WEEK_START of 2021-02-22 and WEEK_END of 2021-02-28. I thought that the SET DATEFIRST 1 line would solve the problem, but it did not. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you?

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE
    @d date='2021-02-28'

select @d [Date]
,DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw, @d)+1, @d) WEEK_START
,DATEADD(dd, 7-DATEPART(dw, @d), @d) WEEK_END
```

OUPTUP:

```
Date        WEEK_START  WEEK_END
2021-02-28  2021-02-22  2021-02-28
```

Comment: @Bohemian yes, any doubts?